# Is there a way to prevent a type intersection from bypassing a union type restriction?

Tags: typescript

In the following example:

```js
function fn(_: number | { a: number }) {}


declare const x: number & { a: string };
                            // ^___ it's type string instead of number

fn(x); // no error


declare const y: string & { a: number };
              // ^___ it's type string instead of number

fn(y); // no error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAKA+gLkWEBbAIwFMAnRAH0QG9EBDbXQ0xAXwEpqWAoHgEyIgAbWiSKIICAM5READwb5iZAGTU62aSRhgA5qwDcXAJAnTRgPTnEAPXR3EMKAHJJiKAE8ADmM3a926SJaXkQ4YBxFUh4UVFk2fURLHDhEUhI4Eh4ufiERMQkwaUR3DSgtXURVGnoIpjIWQ1NERKtbe0cXNy8fMr8HQqggkLDapWi0d3iW5NSSdMygA)

Is there a way to prevent the intersection type from working? or prevent the intersection type from being partly incorrect?

Thank you.

Edit:

You could get the intersection type by doing `Object.assign(1, { a: 9 })`.

Since real overloads don't exists in Javascript, the purpose of such a function would be to do something when the argument is a number (namely use it as an index) and another thing when the argument is a record with properties of a particular type.

To be able to operate on both types of arguments at the same time (like a javascript overload), it would need to be able to restrict the intersection type, which is why I'm asking if it's possible.

Thank you.

Comment: "being partly incorrect" --- it's not incorrect, both `x` and `y` values are assignable to the `_` argument.

Comment: @jcalz yes, doing `Object.assign(1, { a: 9 })` will give you that type. I'll edit to add more context.

Comment: Of course I know it's `Number` instead of `number` , it's the same as doing `Object(1)` first. For practical effects (i.e. it being used as an index), `Number` and `number` would act the same.
It would also be the same as having only the object with properties, and implementing `[Symbol.toPrimitive]()` btw, but it's more verbose.

Comment: The reason for doing this, would be having the duality of purpose in the function. It could be solved by having multiple arguments (because an overload would result in the same problem), but I would prefer to deviate from it being a design discussion.
Plus the example is actually simplified. In my use case, the type restriction is actually the return type of a higher order function which would be a single value (unless returning a array, and checking for that, etc, etc).

Comment: Both appear in my code. I think it started getting confusing because we started to discuss the difference between the actual runtime type and the typescript interpretation which doesn't change the question. What I meant by simplified is that the question poses the same problem in the parameter to a function rather than the returning type of a function returned by another function (my actual code). But with the solution you provided we're getting somewhere, wonderful. I made some changes to allow the intersection and it works great!

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer explaining when I get a chance.  Probably not for a bit because it is now my bedtime.

Comment: [playground link is too long, here's part one](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAClC8UB2BXAtgIwgJwNwChRIoB5BKAbygEMAuZdLbKAXwMPGhmwEs0fgPAG7REAZ2C8kAcygAfBphzyoGHtJ5JgK1ABtdKlEgAmEAGaaIxlRgD2t3RGpICRaAFEAHsAgmx3PgFhCAAeABUAGigw7BQIKIAxal0xCAA+cjCoCG9fYzFYXn5BESgAfmjY6HoklIhXTigvHz8SDAArCABjYHComLjE5NSMxCyclvyoWw7u7QqB6qha1IbiZryxACFbYAALPsrB5eH08g2-AOLgw4v8ts6ew8WhurTXkfY3aIgJcNGmrk-Dt9s9skCpnAFuDJgUyND6EgICJmIjkTgoncxA85mCJptSOVolA0Sj+jCCVDiaScGk0gQgA)

Comment: [here's part 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAeAKogpgDylsAEwGdEAFRAH0QHkA+ACgH0AuRdLYqDOgSkQDeiAL4AoUSgYBGXgG5EAegWI4AawCGATwlgGAInUAjCHrmLlWAE6W4lnQyHq2AThFmlKjdsmO2B43pu8h5WNnb2NIYAVljQAHTqxMQwAOa6-iYANIKIToiuwrzuFta2EdGxUAlJqbpS2b6IGYGFxdil4ZKRMfGJyWnSDbkubm0AbuoANjCEcYgADlbAlXGiQA)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work with a return value, which is my actual use case.
[This is more akin to what I would like](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAClC8UB2BXAtgIwgJwNwChRIoB5BKAbygEMAuZdLbKAXwP3wGMAbagZz5QAgpXxRxUNAH4AFAEp6cAD6kCLDl14CoAISgQAHsAhIAJoJEUxEtPMpRsEYCmxIoARlysoAeh9QAewBrCBAAOnx1TX5BAGF9IxNzYVEJSTsqR2dXezooAE5WLxZff2DQiKieGKgAEQTjMwtUmwyHJxc3EgwAKwhOYDCYgEsAcyQZdwAaXPpCljli0sCQ8MiOau0AUQak5qs02zl7LM7SXv7BkfGZAHI+YGxbmao8+cXvPyg+AAsAlG4pn02GwAWwlQ2WkEADFdk0UgdWsdMh0ct0+gMhgIxhNprMoPdHrdWB8Sl9fv9AcDQeD1kA)

Comment: [this is my failed attempt](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAClC8UB2BXAtgIwgJwNwChRIoB5BKAbygEMAuZdLbKAXwMPGhmwEs0fgPAG7REAZ2C8kAcygAfBphzyoGHtJ5JgK1ABtdKlEgAmEAGaaIxlRgD2t3RGpICRaAFEAHsAgmx3PgFhCAAeABUAGigw7BQIKIAxal0xCAA+cjCoCG9fYzFYXn5BESgAfmjY6HoklIhXTigvHz8SDAArCABjYHComLjE5NSMxCyclvyoWw7u7QqB6qha1IbiZryxACFbYAALPsrB5eH08g2-AOLgw4v8ts6ew8WhurTXkfY3aIgJcNGmrk-Dt9s9skCpnAFuDJgUyND6EgICJmIjkTgoncxA85mCJptSOVolA0Sj+jCCVDiaScGk0ux8F1dNQxAUAIKUfBQblQNBlcIUvywFQkNIACgAlPQwr9emF6fgWPhGczWVAtoKphyKFyeWhJZQoNgIMAUNgkFAAIy4VhQAD0dqgYj2thQumsWGmAGsICAAHSK-BAA)

Comment: I should probably add the more complicated use case in the question, but thanks for the advance and have a good night.

Comment: You're right, it's my bad I didn't realize it might be solvable in the parameter list scenario yet still not in the inheritance scenario, I didn't start with that because I didn't know a solution to either. I'll edit so you can write your answer and ask a new question with the second scenario.

Comment: But please, don't imply I treat this as ongoing tech support, I feel bad, I know well that any answer coming this way is voluntary and I don't expect a compulsory engage or resolution from anyone. I might have simply thought that since I already edited the question to add more context, a second edit wouldn't be harmful. It's ok to do a follow up question as you pointed out.

Comment: I didn't know about tsplay.dev btw, thank you.

Comment: new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77728642/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-a-type-intersection-from-bypassing-a-union-type-restri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't want to help enforce your constraint because it goes against the rules of the type system, such as: every member of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) is assignable to the union (`T` is assignable to `T | U` for all `T` and `U`) and an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) is assignable to every member of the intersection (`T & U` is assignable to `T` for all `T` and `U`).  That means a normal function that accepts `number | {a: number}` should also accept `number` and therefore `number & {a: string}`.  And similarly it should accept `{a: number}` and therefore `string & {a: number}`.  If you find yourself wanting to prevent such assignments, you might want to spend some time examining your use cases to make sure that you've got a very good reason to do so, since you'll be working against the TypeScript type system.  I will assume from now on that we do want to proceed.

---

Intersections of [primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) with object types in TypeScript are a convenient fiction which are allowed only because they help simulate [nominal types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).  See [the FAQ entry for "Can I make type aliases nominal?"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal).  These are known as "branded primitives". Technically such types cannot exist and they "should" therefore reduce to [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  The fact that this does not happen means that we can expect to see some weird exceptional behavior.

The particular weird thing is that `string & {a: number}` is seen as assignable both to `string` and to `object`, even though `string & object` is `never`.  If you try to express "a `number` that is not an `object`" or "a `{a: number}` that is an `object`", those end up looking like just `number` and `{a: number}` for any reasonable implementation, and nothing changes.

The only way I can think of to express this is via [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  Instead of checking against, say, `string & object` (which is `never`), we check something like `T extends string ? T extends object ? ⋯ : ⋯ : ⋯`.

Here's a possible implementation:

```
type Primitive = string | number | bigint | null | undefined | boolean | symbol;
function fn<T extends number | { a: number }>(
    _: T extends object ? T extends Primitive ? number & { a: number } : T : T
) { }
```

I've defined `Primitive` as the union of all primitive types, so that we prevent all (non-`number`) primitives and not just `string`.  The check `T extends object ? T extends Primitive ? ⋯ : T : T` will essentially only catch branded primitives, which are assignable both to `Primitive` and to `object`.  Then once we know we have a branded primitive, we can make sure we only accept the one you want to accept, which is `number & {a: number}`.

Let's test it out:

```
fn(1); // okay
fn("abc"); // error
fn({ a: 9 }); // okay
fn({ a: "abc" }); // error
fn(Object.assign(1, { a: 9 })); // okay
fn(Object.assign("abc", { a: 9 })); // error
fn(Object.assign(1, { a: "abc" }); // error
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAzsRAOwHMoAfKQgVyQCMI5ypaFiFDgnqAbbpqwgBMIAM3YRBTWgHtp3CAENCTXCDpyA3ACgRAgMZppykYQA8AFSgQAHsAhDclGvUYUA3lAUAuJ3QZQAXwA+AAotKAioAH0fSxs7ByhpWgArCAMoAH4oONt7QUd4ZFQMaGzqP0YAMigPb18XQKhY5pytAEpawK0dQhCARnaNKAB6EaSAawUQXpCAIgVaPTmh0fGGOGk4WbqfAE5A1bHJ6Z3PHwWlucPh442t2YB5VPTgADoFXFxWPv6AGi69QOAXaR3G0imMxMIWeaQMHy+P3mi2WAN2UGBoNu6zgm220NhrwR32IvzR5ygl2WNzWVlxDx6WiAA)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify that an "a" property must be a number, except if the overall value is a number the "a" property may be absent, you will need to make that explicit:

```
function fn(_: (number & { a?: number }) | { a: number }) {}
```

Alternatively, if you want to specify that if the overall value is a number it should not have any "a" property at all, I think the best you can do is this:

```
function fn(_: (number & { a?: never }) | { a: number }) {}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for the second case.