# Is there a way to prevent a type intersection from bypassing a union type restriction when the type is the return type of an inherited method?

Tags: typescript

I recently posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77720381/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-a-type-intersection-from-bypassing-a-union-type-restri).

I started with the problem with the type being in the parameter list (which turned out to be solvable using generics), but I'm actually concerned with the following scenario where the typing is in the return type of an inherited method (which can't be solved the same way).

Is there a way to prevent the intersection type from working when it does not fully satisfies the expected union type?

```js
abstract class A {
    abstract m(): number | { a: number }; // expected type either number or { a: number } (or both).
}

class B extends A {
    declare x: number; // type is only number.

    m() { return this.x; } // okey.
}

class C extends A {
    declare x: { a: number }; // type is only { a: number }.

    m() { return this.x; } // okey.
}

class D extends A {
    declare x: number & { a: number }; // both intersected types satisfy the expected type.

    m() { return this.x; } // okey.
}

class E extends A {
    declare x: number & { a: string }; // part of the intersection doesn't satisfy the expected type.
                          // ^___ it's string instead of number

    m() { return this.x; } // should error.
}

class F extends A {
    declare x: string & { a: number }; // part of the intersection doesn't satisfy the expected type.
            // ^___ it's string instead of number

    m() { return this.x; } // should error.
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggg3gKAUIVEhngQFsAKASgC4EA7AVwpAFMoEAfXYhlm04IAvgG4EAekkJ2ADwAO7eOwAmCCAE8lsgJYQAFsMEcuAey45+TVqdEIqFhCDOGaAOjwi8eFGgwAQrJyEOyMqhjY+ACQqsqoUOwIcgK2nBLSGtpJuhhmjMiaNkJQngRE1DR8iRDMUIwaBrnuchIiUjJmANbsmp7evqjoCADCwaHhkbh4sfHAickMVsCpJaIZMlo6uQj5hXwrxXYiZUSUtNXstfWNza32md29-T5+wwAi42ERWNOzfgsUkdhAAyA6rY4bZyuAwIXSMUJQMDKULqLbsDBgYAQXIAMyKhiS8iUKjR2VOFQuVhqdQahjubQ6ux6fS8ryGGAAol9Jr8YnEAUkgSZQeCEKR4QBzdZMhTzRBmXGNHIIzjI+C6fIIVRmDGMADkiCxOLA+OVwRJqKySk80Tt9sImQAegB9N1wiD6zHQKVwxiQdjAdSK4FQHxnSqXa50ppgFqMzJgAxmZjIdScKAWF6DfwIABiPJ+URmAoSQoYEsY0rBywhwnEsvluyVhL9iPVOK1Or1hvF2LxBKMFpRamt7FtdudbpdHq94p9Vb9AaDzdD4cpVWpV1ptzj93aieTqfTUEzpTZQA)

Thank you.

Comment: ① "Bypassing a union type restriction" is not what's happening. `T & U` is always assignable to `T | V` for all `T`, `U`, and `V`, by the definitions of intersection and union.  There is no such thing as "partially incorrect intersection". ② Intersections of primitives and object types behave strangely and make your question even more complicated. I would like to see a [mre] that motivates their use.  If you're using branded primitives, why?  If you're using `Object.assign` on *primitives*, why? ⊛ I love answering TS questions but I'm very wary of touching this one because of these issues.

Comment: Sure, we already know how the intersection and union are implemented to work in the typescript type system as you pointed out in the other question. I'm using "bypassing" and "partially incorrect" in the general sense of the words. The important takeaway is not the use of those words but the desired outcome.

If you'd like hear cases for wanting to code something like that, no worries, I'll edit and add some. But beware, I would just like to know if there's a way I can use typescript to acomodate my goal, rather than alternative ways to do things for me to acomodate typescript.

Comment: I think in order to do this (without looking for alternative ways to do things, even though that might make you happier in the long run) you'll need to keep using generics and conditional types, possibly as the answer already posted below suggests.   Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired functionality, you can utilize a class template in combination with the `IfEquals` utility type, as shown in the following example from Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53808212). This approach involves explicitly defining each potential legal union type as the return type for your function. Here's how you can implement it:

```
type IfEquals<T, U> =
  (<G>() => G extends T ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<G>() => G extends U ? 1 : 2) ? T : never;

abstract class A<R = unknown> {
    abstract m(): IfEquals<R, number> | IfEquals<R, { a: number }> | IfEquals<R, (number | { a: number })> | IfEquals<R, (number & { a: number })>;
}

class B extends A<number | { a: number }> {
    readonly x: number | { a: number };

    m() { return this.x; } // This works as expected.
}

class C extends A<number & { a: string }> {
    declare x: number & { a: string };

    m() { return this.x; } // This will result in an error.
}

class E extends A {
    declare x: number & { a: string };

    m() { return this.x; } // This will also result in an error.
}
```